# How to load our own data set for training

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to train a model that will tell us the PM2.5(this value describe AQI) of any image. For this I use CNN. I am using tensorflow for this purpose. I am new in this field.Please tell me how we upload our own dataset and separate its name and tags. The format of image name is "imageName_tag"(e.g ima01_23.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need more information about your case regarding the "how upload our own dataset".

However, if your dataset is on your computer and you want to access it from python, i invite you to take a look at the libraries "glob" and "os".

To split the name (which in your case is "imageName_tag") you can use:

```
string = "imageName_tag"
name, tag = string.split('_')
```

As you'll have to do it for all your data, you'll have to use it in a loop and store the extracted informations in lists.